# Visual Studio Installer : How to run application if it already installed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-installer

I have application on C# created in Visual Studio 2015. I added installer project and created installer of my application. My installer saves path to install directory of my app in registry.

Is it posible when run installer to check if app is currently istalled - run it, if not - run installation progress?

My purpose is: I need to create a CD disk with my app. When user inserts this cd disk at first time the installer is run. When user inserts this cd disk another time the installed app must run without install process.

Comment: What kind of installer is this?

Comment: Why? An installer's job is only to install an application. Users aren't going to use the *installer* to run the application. You *could* create a custom action that tried to run the application but that would be *very* unusual and confusing.

Comment: To my knowledge, you can't "run the app" via the setup if it is already installed. You can specify to remove previous versions and detect new installed versions via the setup properties in Visual Studio.

Comment: The expected behavior for an installer is to offer to customize/remove or repair an already installed application. Breaking this is a very bad idea

Comment: Thanks.
What will you advise me to use for my purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autoplay of inserted CDs is something that is frequently turned off (the security risk) so I wouldn't count on anything automatic happening.

The normal behavior of inserting a CD and "running" it for an installed product is that a maintenance/repair operation occurs. It's probably not a good idea to change this behavior. Also, if your installed product is broken in some way and goes into repair mode then the user will be asked to insert the CD to get the install repaired (such as installing deleted files) and again it wouldn't be a good idea if inserting the CD broke this behavior and decided to run your app instead (or at the same time).

So this isn't really an install question because it's about the design of the program you put on the CD that deals with all this when the user runs the CD. It will need to see if the product is already installed, and if it is then run the installed app, except that the user may have put the CD in because Windows asked them to for a repair, and I don't know how the program can detect that it was inserted for a repair. If the product isn't installed then you run your setup. This all code you'd need to write, dealing with the issues that people have raised.

There are many issues here, and also I've never seen a product that behaves like this, so that's something else that users don't expect. It's not a good idea, as everyone is saying, and you almost need to decide which features of Windows Installer you want to break, such as repair and maintenance.